# How can find the empty files that I downloaded using the curl command?

Tags: bash, shell

I executed  curl command to retrieve, from the following webpage "http://files.rcsb.org/view/IDENTIFIER.pdb"
the PDB files that have an identifier starting with 1W followed by any digit and ending with any
upper case letter and save each into a separate file.
But some of these files don't exist. My question is how to delete them.

I first run this command to download the files:
**curl [http://files.rcsb.org/view/1W[0-9][A-Z].pdb](http://files.rcsb.org/view/1W%5B0-9%5D%5BA-Z%5D.pdb) -o file_#1#2.txt**

I got 260 files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKOC1.png)

What command should I run to remove empty files? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, [the `find` command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-command-in-linux-with-examples/) has a `-delete` parameter you can use. It also has has a `-size` parameter for filtering on size. The combination of both leads to this:

```
find ./ -type f -size 0 -delete
```

The URL, I refer to, gives some more background information and examples concerning the command.

Good luck